# In IPython, how do you save and append to a file rather than overwriting it?

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython, you can save parts of the current session by doing `%save my_useful_session 10-20 23` to save lines 10-20 and line 23 to the file `my_useful_session.py`.  If `my_useful_session.py` already exists, IPython promps you to overwrite the fail rather than append it.   How can you append to an already existing file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2131/files#diff-57c1c5ff5864bc0b430262a744c7eb81R755).  You can append to an existing file by passing the `-a` option to the save command.  Note that the option must be passed before any of the other input.  Ex:  `%save -a my_useful_session 10-20 23` will append lines 10-20 and 23 to the file `my_useful_session.py`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following:

```
%save -a
```